# get Text on TextView's background

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

can any one tell me how to get background image over TextView's text 
like this

[image]

i m able to get background image over TextView but image is showing below on textView  like this 
[image]

can anyone help me

thanks in Advance

Comment: I consider using Framelayout for this case

Comment: i used Framelayout , but it still not works

Comment: please than post your xml code if possible

Comment: i used Realtivelayout within LinearLayout it is working now thanks for your reply and time you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I don't know what you plan to do but this looks like a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

2) But if you want to stick with this configuration, use this kind of layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewPercentage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewPercentage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewPercentage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPercentage"
        android:weightSum="10"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProgress"
            android:background="#0F0"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTotal"
            android:background="#000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="30%"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPercentage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And inside your Java code, use this to change the text :

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPercentage)).setText("10%");
```

Use this to change the "percentage" of color inside the bar :

```
int weight = 5; // put a number between 0 and 10 here

LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParamsProgress = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
myLayoutParamsProgress.weight = weight;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParamsTotal = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
myLayoutParamsTotal.weight = 10 - weight;

findViewById(R.id.imageViewProgress).setLayoutParams(myLayoutParamsProgress);
findViewById(R.id.imageViewTotal).setLayoutParams(myLayoutParamsTotal);
```

Comment: this is What, i m looking for my app, i used Progressbar but not able to find out how it works, i m going to use your code and back to u

Comment: thanks for your answer, it will help me get my app working. :)

Comment: @Rahulkumar No problem, if you have any issue, feel free to comment on this thread with `@NinoLenoska` so I get a notification.

Comment: can u please give me example of progressbar @NinoLenoska

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :
Set your background to `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i need to give width of TextView. applying now and get back to you

Comment: It's not a problem, you can give it a width.

Comment: i used Realtivelayout within LinearLayout it is working now thanks for your reply and time you used

Answer (score 2):

Please try this hope it will help you

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_solid_light_holo" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Frame Layout` put an `ImageView` above your `TextView`.
Hope this is what you are asking for.

Or use relative layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

And set image to this imageview will display above the textview.

Comment: currently, i m using RelativeLayout, applying now  get back to you

Comment: it still not working, can u please suggest any other Solution

Answer (score 0):

U can set the background to the textview like:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ur_background_image"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="30%" />
```